# MongoDB - previous and next inside subdocument

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to obtain 3 subdocuments from my collection using aggregation framework (I'd like to use only aggregation because this is part of a long pipeline).
I know only one property of one subdocument. I need to retrieve that `subdoc` and the previous and next one too.
Example:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Title 34",
    "subDoc": {
      "subtitle": "subtitle 8",
      "order": 8
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Title 34",
    "subDoc": {
      "subtitle": "subtitle 6",
      "order": 6
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Title 34",
    "subDoc": {
      "subtitle": "subtitle 11",
      "order": 11
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Title 34",
    "subDoc": {
      "subtitle": "subtitle 13",
      "order": 13
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Title 34",
    "subDoc": {
      "subtitle": "subtitle 7",
      "order": 7
    }
  }
]
```

I knew only one subtitle order (for example, "11"), and I need to obtain something like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Title 34",
    "subDoc": [
      {
        "subtitle": "subtitle 8",
        "order": 8
      },
      {
        "subtitle": "subtitle 11",
        "order": 11
      },
      {
        "subtitle": "subtitle 13",
        "order": 13
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried with unwind, order, limit, but I can get only the previous OR the next document, not both.

Playground here:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/0228GD-b6oZ

Comment: You can group all the documents into an array, then find the index of the array element you know about. This will give you the previous and next index values - and the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$sort` by `order` in ascending order
- `$group` by `title` and make `subDoc` array of object and `subDocOrder` array of order field
- `$addFields` to add three fields `prevOrder` previous order number (`$indeOfArray` to get previous index of 11 and subtract 1) and `nextOrder` next order number (`$indeOfArray` to get next index of 11 and add 2), `sizeSubDoc` size of `subDoc` array

```
let order = 11;
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { "subDoc.order": 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$title",
      subDoc: { $push: "$subDoc" },
      subDocOrder: { $push: "$subDoc.order" }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      prevOrder: {
        $subtract: [{ $indexOfArray: ["$subDocOrder", order] }, 1]
      },
      nextOrder: {
        $add: [{ $indexOfArray: ["$subDocOrder", order] }, 2]
      },
      sizeSubDoc: { $size: "$subDoc" }
    }
  },
```

- `$project` to show required fields, and get `subDoc` array
- `$range` to get the range from 2 conditions, first check `prevOrder` is less than 0 then return 0 otherwise `preOrder`, second check `nextOrder` is greater than size of `subDoc` array then return size otherwise return `nextOrder`, finally we got start number and end number of range
- `$map` to iterate loop of above created range array that we are going to input in map, and check in will return `$arrayElemAt` form range array

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      title: "$_id",
      subDoc: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: [order, "$subDocOrder"] },
          {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $range: [
                  { $cond: [{ $lt: ["$prevOrder", 0] }, 0, "$prevOrder"] },
                  { $cond: [{ $gt: ["$nextOrder", "$sizeSubDoc"] }, "$sizeSubDoc", "$nextOrder"] }
                ]
              },
              in: { $arrayElemAt: ["$subDoc", "$$this"] }
            }
          },
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xdwyH50IuYu)

---

**Test cases covered:**

> 1. What if current element is first element means don't have previous element?
>    (this will return current and next elements only)
> 2. What if current element is last element means don't have next element?
>    (this will return current and previous elements only)
> 3. What if `subDoc` only have one element that is current?
>    (this will return only single current element)
> 4. What is your input 11 not found?
>    (this will return blank array)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your use case using the following stages:

1. $sort the `subDoc.order`
2. $group all the documents into an array
3. Find the index of the previous and current array elements
4. $group based on `title` and use $addToSet to append required docs
5. $project stages to transform data into expected output

Edge cases to consider based on the sample doc:

> 1. No previous document
>    Eg: `subDoc.order=6`  ,return docs [6,7]
> 2. No current document
>    Eg: `subDoc.order= 14`, return empty
> 3. No next document
>    Eg: `subDoc.order= 13` ,return docs [11,13]
> 4. Current document exists, but no previous or next document, when `document count=1`

You can use the following aggregation query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "subDoc.order": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "title": 1,
      "order": "$subDoc.order",
      "subtitle": "$subDoc.subtitle"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      count: {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "previousDoc": {
        $subtract: [
          {
            $indexOfArray: [
              "$data.order",
              11
            ]
          },
          1
        ]
      },
      "nextDoc": {
        $add: [
          {
            $indexOfArray: [
              "$data.order",
              11
            ]
          },
          1
        ]
      },
      currentDoc: {
        $indexOfArray: [
          "$data.order",
          11
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "next": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$data",
          "$nextDoc"
        ]
      },
      previous: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$data",
          "$previousDoc"
        ]
      },
      current: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$data",
          "$currentDoc"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$data.title",
      p: {
        "$addToSet": {
          $cond: [
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  $lt: [
                    "$currentDoc",
                    1
                  ]
                },
                
              ]
            },
            "$$REMOVE",
            "$previous"
          ]
        }
      },
      c: {
        "$addToSet": {
          $cond: [
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  $lt: [
                    "$currentDoc",
                    0
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $ne: [
                    "$count",
                    1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "$$REMOVE",
            "$current"
          ]
        }
      },
      n: {
        "$addToSet": {
          $cond: [
            {
              $lt: [
                "$nextDoc",
                1
              ]
            },
            "$$REMOVE",
            "$next"
          ]
        }
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      subDoc: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$p",
          "$c",
          "$n"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "subDoc.subtitle": 1,
      "subDoc.order": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W_Tmme4Yhu9)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution if you really want to do it with aggregation but the structure is modified you can map it at your convenience

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "subDoc.order": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$title",
      "next": {
        "$push": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$gt": [
                "$subDoc.order",
                11
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": "$_id",
              "item": "$$CURRENT.subDoc"
            },
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      },
      "prev": {
        "$push": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$lt": [
                "$subDoc.order",
                11
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": "$_id",
              "item": "$$CURRENT.subDoc"
            },
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      },
      "current": {
        "$push": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$subDoc.order",
                11
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": "$_id",
              "item": "$$CURRENT.subDoc"
            },
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      next: {
        $slice: [
          "$next",
          1
        ]
      },
      prev: {
        $slice: [
          "$prev",
          -1
        ]
      },
      current: 1
    }
  }
])
```

The output looks like this

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Title 34",
    "current": [
      {
        "id": "33",
        "item": {
          "order": 11,
          "subtitle": "subtitle 11"
        }
      }
    ],
    "next": [
      {
        "id": "15",
        "item": {
          "order": 12,
          "subtitle": "subtitle 12"
        }
      }
    ],
    "prev": [
      {
        "id": "34",
        "item": {
          "order": 8,
          "subtitle": "subtitle 8"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```